# MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor inside onBindViewHolder

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-viewholder

I'm getting this error when I click in my menu icon:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: MenuPopupHelper cannot be used without an anchor
```

I have this code:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

...

holder.imageButtom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopup(holder.imageButtom, position, post.getPid());
            }
        });
```

and the showpopup

```
private void showPopup(View view, final int position, final String id) {
    View menuItemView = view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, menuItemView);
    MenuInflater inflate = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflate.inflate(R.menu.cardview_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.delete_id:
                    Posts.remove(position);
                    notifyItemRemoved(position);
                    // do what you need.
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}
```

any ideas why this error when I click in my imagebuttom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're passing wrong `View` while calling `showPopup(View view, final int position, final String id)`. Once `showPopup` invoked, you're finding a particular View Id namely `R.id.card_view` with this

```
View menuItemView = view.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
```

And you're calling it by passing the ImageButton itself

```
showPopup(holder.imageButtom, position, post.getPid());
```

which I'm guessing the root cause of the problem. I think you intent to pass different view which consists of the card view(`R.id.card_view`) you're looking in `showPopup`.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, I'll try to change it according your answer.

Comment: No problem. I'm pretty much sure you're giving the wrong View and as a result, isn't getting an View(anchor, in this case) while trying to find that particular card view. Still, let me know if my finding actually works.